Apache stops displaying web page after ubuntu dist-upgrade on freescout server
Last week I set up an ubuntu 22.04LTS server and ran the freescout install script.  I was able to configure and start using freescout , then I thought it would be a good idea (clearly not) to upgrade the packages on the server with a apt update && apt dist-upgrade.  now when browsing to the freescout server, it shows an index page rather than the website itself.
being new to apache , PHP, mysql, etc , I'm not certain what logs to look at or where even the trouble may be.
here is the list of packages that upgraded post install:
ubuntu-pro-client-l10n:amd64 (31.2.2~22.04, automatic), python3-magic:amd64 (2:0.4.24-2, automatic), ubuntu-pro-client:amd64 (31.2.2~22.04, automatic)
Upgrade: dpkg:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, 1.21.1ubuntu2.3), tcpdump:amd64 (4.99.1-3build2, 4.99.1-3ubuntu0.2), dmidecode:amd64 (3.3-3, 3.3-3ubuntu0.1), libxtables12:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), initra
mfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.4), udev:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), coreutils:amd64 (8.32-4.1ubuntu1, 8.32-4.1ubuntu1.2), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.18.6-1, 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.0
4.3), python3-tz:amd64 (2022.1-1, 2022.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), iptables:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:22.04.13, 1:22.04.19), apt:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.12), libnftables1:amd64
(1.0.2-1ubuntu2, 1.0.2-1ubuntu3), libqmi-proxy:amd64 (1.30.4-1, 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), sosreport:amd64 (4.3-1ubuntu2.1, 4.5.6-0ubuntu1~22.04.2), modemmanager:amd64 (1.18.6-1, 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3), crypts
etup-bin:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), libunwind8:amd64 (1.3.2-2build2, 1.3.2-2build2.1), kbd:amd64 (2.3.0-3ubuntu4, 2.3.0-3ubun
tu4.22.04), libldap-common:amd64 (2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, 2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.26.2-1build1, 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubu
ntu3.12), ufw:amd64 (0.36.1-4build1, 0.36.1-4ubuntu0.1), sg3-utils:amd64 (1.46-1build1, 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1, 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2), libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27
+dfsg2-3ubuntu1, 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.12), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.6.1, 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.6), initramfs-tools-bin:amd
64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.4), apparmor:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1, 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3), libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.22.2, 0.99.22.9), libsystemd
0:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), libnss-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), libapparmor1:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1, 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3), irqbalance:amd64 (1.8.0-1build1, 1.8.0-1u
buntu0.2), libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1, 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1.2), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.99.22.2, 0.99.22.9), python-apt-common:amd64 (2.3.0ubuntu2.1, 2.4.0ubuntu3), libgpgme
11:amd64 (1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4, 1.16.0-1.2ubuntu4.2), libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, 2.5.17+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), libudev1:amd64 (249.1
1-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1), motd-news-config:amd64 (12ubuntu4.2, 12ubun
tu4.6), libsgutils2-2:amd64 (1.46-1build1, 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), fwupd-signed:amd64 (1.44+1.2-3, 1.51.1~22.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1), cloud-init:amd64 (23.1.2-0ubuntu0~22.04.1, 24.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.1), sg3-utils
-udev:amd64 (1.46-1build1, 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.3, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.4), open-vm-tools:amd64 (2:12.1.5-3~ubuntu0.22.04.4, 2:12.3.5-3~ubuntu0.22.04.1), libmbim-proxy:am
d64 (1.26.2-1build1, 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1), ubuntu-server-minimal:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), base-files:amd64 (12ubuntu4.2, 12ubuntu4.6), gzip:amd64 (1.10-4ubuntu4, 1.10-4ubuntu4.1), mdadm:amd64 (4.2-0ubuntu1,
4.2-0ubuntu2), cryptsetup-initramfs:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2), python3-apt:amd64 (2.3.0ubuntu2.1, 2.4.0ubuntu3), snapd:amd64 (2.58+22.04.1, 2.61.3+22.04), python3-distro-info:amd64 (1.1build
1, 1.1ubuntu0.2), libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2), multipath-tools:amd64 (0.8.8-1ubuntu1.22.04.1, 0.8.8-1ubuntu1.22.04.4), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.52ubuntu0.1, 0.52ubuntu0.6), li
bip6tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), libqmi-glib5:amd64 (1.30.4-1, 1.32.0-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), cryptsetup:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2), distro-info:amd64 (1.1build1, 1.1ubuntu0.2), l
ibdrm2:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), netplan.io:amd64 (0.104-0ubuntu2.1, 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.4, 2.2
0.11-0ubuntu82.5), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.140ubuntu13, 0.140ubuntu13.4), ubuntu-server:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7, 249.11-0ubuntu3.12), apt-utils:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.12), ubu
ntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:22.04.13, 1:22.04.19), libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.9~22.04.1, 31.2.2~22.04), ethtool:amd64 (1:5.16-1, 1:5.16-1ubuntu0.1
), git-man:amd64 (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.9, 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.10), kpartx:amd64 (0.8.8-1ubuntu1.22.04.1, 0.8.8-1ubuntu1.22.04.4), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.4, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5), libnetplan0
:amd64 (0.104-0ubuntu2.1, 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.4, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5), fwupd:amd64 (1.7.5-3, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.481, 1.481.1), update-notifier-comm
on:amd64 (3.192.54, 3.192.54.8), python3-debian:amd64 (0.1.43ubuntu1, 0.1.43ubuntu1.1), nftables:amd64 (1.0.2-1ubuntu2, 1.0.2-1ubuntu3)

Check your vhost settings in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and make sure DocumentRoot points to the location where your website's files are stored. By default, it points to /var/www/html. Move your website files there and it will start working again.
